# MATLAB to Python: How to replace nargin functionality

Tags: python, matlab

My MATLAB code goes like this

```
function d = myFun1(a,b,c)
  if nargin<3
     c = myFun2(a,b)
  end
  d = a+b+c;
function c = myFun2(a,b)
  c = a*b;
```

My Python code has to replicate the above and I wrongly tried.

```
def myFun1(a,b, c=myFun2(a,b)):
    d = a+b+c;
    return d;
def myFun2(a,b):
    c = a*b;
    return c;
```

How to replicate the above functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keyword arguments are only evaluated at the time, the function is defined. You have to use a mark, and check it, to do the additional calculation:

```
def myFun1(a, b, c=None):
    if c is None:
        c = myFun2(a, b)
    d = a + b + c
    return d
```